# How to register UICollectionViewCell, HeaderCollectionReusableView in a UITableViewCell subclass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I made a UITableViewCell child class.

```
import UIKit

class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
  }

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
  }
}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
      let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath)
      headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;
      return headerView

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
      let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) 

      footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
      return footerView

    default:

      assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
  }

}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:30.0)
  }
}
```

Now when I run this code, I get crash

```
2017-03-19 12:41:43.298 DemoProject[15229:156486] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UICollectionView.m:4971
2017-03-19 12:41:43.306 DemoProject[15229:156486] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader with identifier HeaderCollectionReusableView - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I well know that it is because Cell or View is not registered. its made by xib.

In UIViewController, we do register in ViewDidLoad, so it works. Similarly, which method is ideal to register nib.

I tried putting code in

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
  }
```

Can any one tell me right way to register Cell within UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Register the collection view cell and supplementary view in `awakeFromNib()` of `UITableViewCell` subclass.

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"Your_Nib_Name"), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "videoCell")
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"Your_Nib_Name"), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCollectionReusableView")
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"Your_Nib_Name"), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCollectionReusableView")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CategoryRow` class, Try this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "<Nib Name>", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCollectionReusableView")
}
```